# VueJS render for once in property

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

i has to use **item.birthdate** in **min** and **v-model** property so, hope i had explain the problem. When i change the date **min** property changing i want to use birth date for once in **min**.

> v-once, v-bind => is not working. So i am here.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="birth" placeholder="B.Date"
v-bind:min="item.birthdate" v-model="item.birthdate" v-if="item.gender > 1" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to initialize the separate data value for `min` attribute and define its value on page load like this:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="birth" placeholder="B.Date"
v-bind:min="min" v-model="item.birthdate" v-if="item.gender > 1" required />

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    item: {
        birthdate: "2001-11-12",
      gender: "2"
    },
    min: null
  },
  created() {
    this.min = this.item.birthdate
  }
})
```

I've created a fiddle for you: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sq8r2f0h/)

Comment: Thank you for suggest an idea, but using **birthdate** as dynamic. i getting in ajax request the data.

As => window.app.Oekle2({rez_odaID: 0,tutarA: 5076.00,tutarS: 4568.40,tutari: 10.00,tutarM: 4230.00,oda: '2',oda_adi: 'Standart Kara Manzaralı Oda',pansiyon: '5',pansiyon_adi: 'Ultra Her Şey Dahil',serbest: false,musteri: [{erkek: '0',musteriadi: '',soyad: '',**bithdate**: ''},{erkek: '3',musteriadi: '',soyad: '',**bithdate**: '2017-08-25'}]});

Comment: You’ll need to move `this.min = this.item.bithdate` to the end of Ajax request then.

Comment: i request an array, so useless this method, thank you anyway :)